# the fonts within SmartArt shapes in the PowerPoint presentation were not replaced as expected by using python

Tags: python, fonts, powerpoint-2016

Question:

Despite using the `Spire.Presentation` library in Python, iterating through each SmartArt shape node, and attempting to modify the font properties, the fonts within SmartArt shapes in the PowerPoint presentation were not replaced as expected.

Can anyone provide insights or alternative approaches to successfully replace the fonts within SmartArt shapes using Python and `Spire.Presentation` library?

Library Used:  Spire.Presentation

This library provides functionalities to work with PowerPoint presentations in Python.

Approach:

Open the PowerPoint presentation using `Spire.Presentation.`
Iterate through each slide in the presentation.
For each slide, iterate through each shape.
Identify SmartArt shapes based on their shape type.

Access the nodes within each SmartArt shape.
Access the text content and font properties within each node.
Check if the font needs to be replaced. If so, replace it with the desired font.
Save the modified presentation.

Code Highlights:

Use spire.presentation.Presentation to open and manipulate PowerPoint presentations.
Access slides using the Slides attribute.
Access shapes within slides using the Shapes attribute.
Identify SmartArt shapes using their shape type (e.g., shape.shape_type == 24).

Access nodes within SmartArt shapes using the nodes attribute.
Access text content and font properties within nodes using appropriate attributes.
Replace fonts as needed.
Save the modified presentation using saveToFile() method.
Result:

The script not successfully modifies fonts within SmartArt shapes in the PowerPoint presentation.
Fonts are not replaced with the desired font.
The modified presentation is saved with the changes applied.

The libraries I've used include python-pptx, spire.presentation, and pptx_ea_font, but I still can't change the font of Chinese, English, and numbers in SmartArt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Answers go in answers, not the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

To successfully replace Chinese text in SmartArt within a program, you need to utilize the COM object model of Microsoft PowerPoint. However, such operations might be subject to limitations imposed by system configurations and security settings, and require a Python environment running on Windows. Please ensure that your system meets the following requirements:

Windows operating system.
Microsoft PowerPoint installed.
Utilization of Python's COM components (can be achieved through the comtypes library).